# TypeError: Cannot read property 'runner' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my angular application I use  AngularJS v1.4.3 (currently latest version)

Also using angular-animate  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js

Using angular-ui-router  ver 2.15
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js

I get an error: cannot read property 'runner' of undefined
[image]

This error **not** appears always, but sometime when i try to change location I got this error.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Where is this 'runner' property being accessed?

Comment: Can you please show us some code. Perhaps https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the error appear when change the page sate, or by click on <a ui-sref="page({ pagename: 'about-us' })" >About us </a> or by change the url to other page.

Comment: I still got this error, just removing the angular-animate resolve this issue, and I  want to use the animate in my project, Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you can find this issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11992). this issue will resolve in v1.4.9

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am late. Kindly check is there any ng-data-animate directive in the HTML. Ideally, it should set on its own. If you are setting it manually then it is wrong.