# AngularJS : Cannot read property 'runner' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typeerror, ng-animate, ui-sref, state.go

**Summary :**
I am having a critical issue in my Angular application. I am using

- `AngularJS v1.4.7`
- `angular-animate`
- `angular-ui-router`

I am getting an error in console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'runner' of undefined'

**Screenshot :**

[image]

**Way to produce the error :**

This `Type Error` not produce every time, but sometime when i try to change the `state` using `ui-sref` from the HTML and `$state.go()` from the controller.

**What I tried so far ?**

I tried this temporary fix in `angular-animate.js` but no progress at all.

[image]

There are lot of open issues in GitHub and also in Stack Overflow.

- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'runner' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525168/typeerror-cannot-read-property-runner-of-undefined)
- [Animate crash: Cannot read property 'runner' of undefined](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11992)

Comment: It is said that 1.4.9 doesn't have this issue. From 1.4.7 it's not a big upgrade.